# Dictionary keys not present though they are being added

Tags: python, dictionary, graph, key-value

This is my code :

```
class member:

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def get_name(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class create_graph:

    def __init__(self):
        self.some_dict = dict()

    def add(self, name):
        if name is None:
            raise TypeError
        print(name not in self.some_dict)
        if name not in self.some_dict:
            self.some_dict[name] = []
        else:
            print(str(name) + "is already present")

    def link(self, p1, p2):
        if p1 in self.some_dict:
            self.some_dict[p1].append(p2)
        else:
            self.some_dict[p1] = [p2]

some_graph = create_graph()

list_person = ['abc', 'xyz', 'mno', 'pqr']

for person in list_person:
    some_graph.add(member(person))

print(len(some_graph.some_dict))

for i in range(len(list_person)-1):
    some_graph.link(i,i+1)

print(len(some_graph.some_dict))
```

I am not able to find the error in this code. 
When the add function is called, I get the True message indicating it is added. The first print statement prints that the number of keys are 4 but after adding the links, it says the keys are 7. 
I want to have just 4 even after adding the link.

Thanks for the help !

Comment: hint: try printing `some_graph.some_dict`

Comment: You are storing instances of class `member` in `some_dict`, but you are then trying to look up strings (names) in that dict. `member("bob")` is not the same as `"bob"`, and furthermore `member("bob") != member("bob")`; they will be different instances with the same name.

Comment: @mad_ I tried testing that. It does give me the correct result. {pqr: [], xyz: [], abc: [], mno: []}. But, my error still remains.

Answer (score 1):

Print out the dictionary in question.

```
print(some_graph.some_dict)
```

produces

```
{<__main__.member object at 0x7fe8326abe80>: [], <__main__.member object at 0x7fe8326abeb8>: [], <__main__.member object at 0x7fe8326abe48>: [], <__main__.member object at 0x7fe8326abef0>: []}
```

The keys of this dictionary are instances of the class `member`, not the strings in the list `list_person`.

I you did:

```
persons_in_graph_dict = {k.name for k in some_graph.some_dict}
for person in list_person:
    print(person)
    print(person in persons_in_graph_dict)
    print()
```

You would get:

```
abc
True

xyz
True

mno
True

pqr
True
```

Answer (score 0):

You can fix the problem by adding a [`__contains__()`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__contains__) method to your `CreateGraph` class that expects a *string* argument called `name`. How to do this and then use it shown in the code below.

**Note:** I have changed all your class names to the CapitalizedWords-style  to conform to the PEP8 coding guidelines (in its [Naming Conventions](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#naming-conventions) section).

```
class Member:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def get_name(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class CreateGraph:
    def __init__(self):
        self.some_dict = dict()

    def add(self, name):
        if name is None:
            raise TypeError

        if name not in self.some_dict:
            self.some_dict[name] = Member(name)
        else:
            print("{} is already present".format(name))

    def __contains__(self, name):  # <-- METHOD ADDED.
        return name in self.some_dict


some_graph = CreateGraph()

list_person = ['abc', 'xyz', 'mno', 'pqr']

for person in list_person:
    some_graph.add(person)

print("checking these names in list_person:", list_person)
for person in list_person:
    if person in some_graph:
        print("Present")
    else:
        print("Not present")
```

Here's the output:

```
checking these names in list_person: ['abc', 'xyz', 'mno', 'pqr']
Present
Present
Present
Present
```

Answer (score -1):

You are storing instances as key. call `name()`to get the name
try testing like below

```
for i in some_graph.some_dict:
    print ((i.name) in list_person)
```